# Universal Publish task fails in Azure Devops Pipeline ( Could not create provinence session)

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-artifacts

I am exploring the azure artifacts service provided by azure devops. I have created a simple c++ helloworld program, which gets compiled and stores the executable in another folder.

To understand how the publishing to azure artifact works, I have copied the executable to the artifact directory, and I call the task to upload the artifact.

Below is the pipeline:

```
steps:

- script: |
    mkdir output
    g++ tests.cpp -o output/test
    cd output
    ls -l
    ./test


- task: CopyFiles@2
  inputs:
    Contents: 'output/**'
    targetFolder: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'testproject'
    publishLocation: 'Container'

    
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: Universal Publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
    vstsFeedPublish: 'Department/E-S-S-Test'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: 'testproject'
    packagePublishDescription: 'containstestdescription'
    versionPublish: '1.0.0'
```

I am getting the following error :

```
##[warning]Could not create provenance session: %s
##[warning]Cannot read properties of null (reading 'sessionId')
##[error]Error: Failed to get package versions
##[error]Packages failed to publish
```

I checked into feed settings, there is a contributor access given to Project Collection Build service group.

What is going wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you may need provide the ProjectID /FeedID in the `vstsFeedPublish`